# Reparing a pinhole leak in fuel line connector

Tags: fuel-system, civic, fuel-leak

My 2013 Civic developed a pinhole leak on the high pressure fuel line where it attaches to the fuel pump.

I'm considering repairing this leak using a fuel-proof sealant like [Seal-All](https://eclecticproducts.com/product/seal-all/) or [JB Tankweld](https://www.jbweld.com/product/tankweld).

One idea, cover the abraded area with [Seal-All](https://eclecticproducts.com/product/seal-all/) to build it back to its original profile. Then, cover the entire area by wrapping a patch of [JB Tankweld](https://www.jbweld.com/product/tankweld) around it to protect it.

Or, the [Seal-All](https://eclecticproducts.com/product/seal-all/) could be wrapped in [WrapIt Silicone tape](https://versachem.com/product/wrapit-repair-silicone-tape/), as it is fuel-proof as well.

https://eclecticproducts.com/product/seal-all/
https://www.jbweld.com/product/tankweld
https://versachem.com/product/wrapit-repair-silicone-tape/

Is there a better way to fix this, short of replacing the high-pressure line?

It looks like the connector was rubbing against the housing which damaged it. I'm not sure how that could happen as the connector isn't close to the body. Perhaps a rock or other foreign material got lodged above the pump and it came out when I opened the cover.  A comment indicated a rodent may have done this, that is defintely plausible.

[image: pinhole leak]

[image: connected to pump]

Comment: They look like they could be teeth marks.

Comment: That never occured to me, but it's definitely possible.  The car is in the driveway and is only driven infrequently. We have chipmunks and squirrels all over the place.  When I took it apart, I could not see anything near it that it would rub against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary fix, it was patched using JB Weld.

The site was roughed up with 100 grit sandpaper and cleaned with carb/choke cleaner.

The pinhole was covered with a small piece of metal foil and pressed flat.  Regular JB Weld (not Quik or Tankweld) is fairly thick, but will run, so I created a small tray underneath the connector out of foil.

The entire connector was covered with a thick, even layer of JB Weld. The JB Weld wraps around the connector and extends past the pinhole on both side.

After letting it cure for 24 hours the fuel line was reconected.  Turning the key to On without starting the car repressurized the fuel system and there were no leaks.  It's been driven 20 miles or so as a test and no leaks so far.

The line will be replaced, I'll update this post if it leaks before then.

[image: Foil on connector]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to repair the connector. You've got about a 95% chance it's going to leak after the repair, and probably closer to a 99.9% chance it's going to leak down the road. Your only option is replacement. This has to do with safety concerns. This concern is heightened because you're dealing with fuel.

The "easiest" fix may be to got to a wrecking yard and find another Honda with the same connector. Cut the tube with enough length to graft it into your current line. Then get a hard line to use to put the two lines together with some hose clamps. This may or may not work, but may be worth a try. The reason I suggest this is because the original line goes all the way to the front without interruption. You'd have to replace the entire thing.

Something to think about before replacement is why did this occur in the first place. It looks to me as though it has been rubbing against the cover. Recognize what was going on there before you ever think about fixing this or you'll suffer the same fate going forward with the next fitting.

Comment: Do you have a source as to why you think it will leak?  The manufacturers of the repair products clearly mention fuel line repair as legitimite uses.

Comment: Because you don't fix something like that? I mean, you can try anything you like: it's your car; it's your life. That is your pressurised fuel side. The "correct" repair is to replace the connector. If you don't replace, you are putting yourself and your passengers at huge risk. But again, it's your vehicle.

Comment: I agree with @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2.  While it may be possible to repair this, I would rather replace the pipe.  There is a good chance the high pressure fuel will eventually break through the repair and start squirting all over the place.  An inconvenient breakdown at the least.  With the addition of an ignition source and you have a major issue.

Answer (score 0):

[RapidFix](https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/p/rapidfix-dual-adhesive-system-high-strength-bond-in-seconds-10-ml-2-pack-6121705/10640147-P?brandName=RapidFix&brandUrlName=rapidfix) will fix it permanently for sure.